# Directly get script representation from Cairo drawing

Tags: graphics, cairo

Is there a way to directly get script representation of a Cairo drawing without saving the script to a file in C++?

I'm trying to get the script in order to do test by comparing scripts. Have tried `cairo_script_create_for_stream` but using streaming seems a little bit overkill for my use case.

Comment: From a quick look at `cairo-script.h`: There are two ways to create a script device. `cairo_script_create(filename)` and `cairo_script_create_for_stream(write_func, closure)`. So, it seems you already found the only way to do this.

Comment: ` but using streaming seems a little bit overkill for my use case.` Could you clarify what you mean here? `cairo_script_create()` basically uses the stream function internally, so they are roughly equivalent. Both approaches do the same amount of streaming.

Comment: I'm trying to output the Cairo script to a string in order to do unit test with it. I eventually go with the `cairo_script_create_for_stream` approach. Thanks for checking the question tho!